# Mp3 player in c#. Problems with the playlist

Tags: c#, listbox, mp3, media-player

I´m currently working in a mp3 player and I want to make a playlist using a `Listbox`, this is what I have:

```
    private void addSongToPlaylist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog2 = new OpenFileDialog(); //Dialog to choose songs
        dialog2.Multiselect = true; // To choose multiple songs in the same dialog
        if (dialog2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            files= dialog2.SafeFileNames;
            paths = dialog2.FileNames;

                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) // Add song to the playlist
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);

                }

        }
```

When I run the code it works properly if I select one or multiple songs in one single dialog.
The problem is that every time I press the "Add Song to playlist" `button` (to add multiple songs separately), the counter variable is reset to zero and therefore I´m not able to add more than one song separately.

I´ve tried declaring a global int variable named "songCount"

```
   int songCount = 0;
```

To use it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) // Add song to the playlist
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(files[songCount]);

                }
    songCount++;
```

When I run the code and I add a second song to the playlist, I get a 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException', I don´t know how to solve the problem. Please help.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the counter. its your array, you dont have enough space in your array for songs

Comment: @KevinAvignon but if that was the case I shouldn´t be able to add multiple songs in one dialog also, right?

Comment: At first glance I don't see anything wrong with your initial block of code. The changes you tried to make definitely won't work. Can you explain what exactly is happening with that first block of code? I don't really understand it from what you've written so far.

Comment: @Tim Basically when I add one song to the `Listbox` it is added in the position "0" of the array right? The problem is that when I add a second song, it is also added in the position "0", and so on.

Comment: No, that's not correct. You're calling ListBox.Items.Add(...) which adds the item to the end of the list. You could break that statement out into two statements to understand it better: `var itemToAdd = files[i]; listBox1.Items.Add(itemToAdd);` The first part gets the item from the list picked by the user. the second part adds it to your running list.